# python - set timeout thresshold in my socket

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to set a timeout thresshold in my socket?

```
import socket

def get_ip(domain):
    ip = ""

    try:
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(domain)
    except socket.gaierror:
        pass
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        return ip

    return ip


ip = get_ip('google.com')
```

For example, if I send a domain which do not have IP, then it's taking a long time in `get_ip()` to return the value (maybe 2-3 seconds). Does any way that I can limit the time for checking this? for example to 1 second.

Comment: have a look at [socket.setdefaulttimeout](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout)

Comment: @AgostBiro I have already tried this `socket.setdefaulttimeout(0.3)` but again it is taking 3-4 seconds to check it.